# How to get the sum of the same column with different status

Tags: laravel

How can i add the same column with different status in a raw query laravel

```
      $result = $this->sales_on_hand->where(function($query) use($request, $dateStart, $dateStart2){
            $query->whereBetween('sales_onhands.created_at', [$dateStart, $dateStart2]);
            if($request->has('branch') && $request->branch != ""){
                $query->where('branch_id', $request->branch);
            }
        })->join('sales_onhand_deposits','sales_onhands.id','=','sales_onhand_deposits.sales_onhand_id'
        )->select(
            DB::raw(
                '
                IFNULL(SUM(sales_onhands.cash_on_hand), 0) AS cash_onhands,
                IFNULL(SUM(sales_onhands.gc_onhand), 0) AS gc_onhands,
                **IFNULL(SUM(sales_onhand_deposits.total), 0) AS total_pending_deposit where sales_onhand_deposits.is_verified = 0 
                IFNULL(SUM(sales_onhand_deposits.total), 0) AS total_approve_deposit where sales_onhand_deposits.is_verified = 1**

                '
            )
    )->get();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `CASE` statements in your `sum()`

```
DB::raw(
    '
    IFNULL(SUM(sales_onhands.cash_on_hand), 0) AS cash_onhands,
    IFNULL(SUM(sales_onhands.gc_onhand), 0) AS gc_onhands,
    IFNULL(SUM(case when sales_onhand_deposits.is_verified = 0 then sales_onhand_deposits.total else 0 end), 0) AS total_pending_deposit  
    IFNULL(SUM(case when sales_onhand_deposits.is_verified = 1 then sales_onhand_deposits.total else 0 end), 0) AS total_approve_deposit
    '
)
```

Comment: Thanks it works . I have another question related to this .for example when im picking date from 2020-01-01 to 2020-01-30 . if there is a data with that has an status of pending it will return as pending . if all the data is verified the data will be verified

Comment: @dacdac Can you please ask a new question with the relevant detail that would be very helpful for us and new visitor can also have a look for this problem

Comment: Okay thanks . but is it okay if i can use the same code from above ? but different question . im sorry im new to this . im a student learning laravel

Comment: @dacdac Yes its completely ok to use this code in your new question, but please add proper details for your issue so that end user will know the problem easily